# Node.js intercept Promise and elaborate Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I am getting started with Node.js + Express and at the moment I am writing my HTTP APIs structure.

I have a controller that exposes some methods using the following pattern:
*my_controller.js*

```
'use strict';
var AppApiFactory = function (express, appService) {

    var api = express.app;

    /* Get all apps ordered by Name Ascending */
    function getAllApps(request, response) {
        appService.getApps(request.query.$expand).then(function (apps) {
            response.status(200).send(apps);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.error('Error occurred in Apps Api: ' + err);
                response.status(500).send("" + err);
        });
    }

    /* Routing */
    api.get('/api/v1/apps', getAllApps);

    return {
        getAllApps: getAllApps,
    };
};

module.exports = AppApiFactory;
```

**appService** is a simple method returned by my ORM which include a Promise and an array of objects.
Now, because I have to implement some ISO/RFC standards, the response has to be translated in a more complex structure like:

```
{
   "data":[my promise array],
   "count":10,
   "type":"xmlns:mytype..."
}
```

How can I intercept the Promise returned by the ORM, modify the content and again return another promise from my Express Controller?
Is this possible?

Maybe it's a stupid question but I still didn't master the concept behind promise.
I am coming from .NET/Java, JavaScript(client) worlds so I am a bit new to JavaScript server-side.

Comment: note: promises existed on the javascript client before it did in node (server side) - where in the code you've posted do you wish to perform this surgical incision? is it just before the `response.status(200).send(apps);` line? (I'm blind guessing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about this specific context, a Promise's `.then()` statement can be chained, where the "thenable" from one `.then()` call flows into the next.

In your situation, it might look something like this:

```
function getAllApps() {
  return appService
    .getApps(request.query.$expand)
    .then(function(apps) {
      response.status(200).send(apps);
      return {
        data: apps,
        count: apps.length,
        type: "xmlns:mytype..."
      }
    })
    .catch(...);
}
```

Calling `getAllApps()` would then return a promise, which takes the original response from `appService.getApps()` and transforms it into the format you're expecting.

```
getAllApps.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});

// {data: [...], length: 10, type: "..."}
```

[See this MDN article on `Promise.prototype.then()` for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the MSDN reference,  I guess I'll spend the weekend in learning more about JavaScript promise

Comment: Any time. MDN* (Mozilla, *not* Microsoft!) - also have a useful reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: I'll have a look at that too, because all my Node module are wrapped with Promises so I better understand what is exactly going on :-)